# What steps are necessary to enable support for Content-Encoding: gzip POST bodies to an ASP.NET application hosted in IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, asp.net, gzip

Sending `Accept-Encoding: gzip` to my server currently upgrades the server responses with gz compression.

Sending `Content-Encoding: gzip` POST bodies to my server does not result in my application being activated.

### Ignoring all other concerns, what are the steps necessary to upgrade my server to support GZipped POST bodies?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET is dynamic compression....

Make sure **dynamic compression** checkbox is checked
see:
http://ericsowell.com/blog/2013/6/7/enabling-gzip-in-iis-on-windows-8

Comment: enabling dynamic compression is required but insufficient to upgrade a server to supporting GZipped POST bodies.  For reference, dynamic compression has been enabled on my server since initial installation. (If dynamic compression was not already enabled, the server would not have replied with gzipped responses on request. I mentioned that the server is replying with gzipped responses in my original question)

Comment: yep, Compressed Request Post  needs a handler in IIS. as well as a way for the browser  to compress.  the RFC 2616 allows for it, even what t respond if it is not supported.  Here is some related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377106/asp-net-webservice-handling-gzip-compressed-request

Comment: The suggestion of an HttpModule is appreciated, but it would require me to enable RAMMFAR on my server. It is extremely desirable to avoid doing this. I implemented a DelegatingHandler inside my application to let http.sys just pass the content on through to my application but when I attempt to do LZMA decompression with the 7zip sdk, the requests get swallowed by the server and are not being dispatched to my application

Comment: LZMA is not GZip. now I'm sure that 7zip API can handle Gzip.  anyway... I think the only other options is to do "file" uploads, like an attachment of a FORM POST. file uploads are much easier then a new HttpModule.  Well good luck

Comment: ... sorry, I skipped some steps in my explanation. I switched over to testing LZMA (de)compression because I couldn't get a GZipStream to decompress without declaring "The magic number in GZip header is not correct." So for investigation purposes, I'm currently trying to do LZMA declared with `Content-Encoding: gzip` There isn't anything apparent from my software that would explain why the original gzip stream could not be deserialized, which prompted my question here. Treat my mention of LZMA as irrelevant information for my question. I'm trying to support gzip POST bodies.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at what happens when you POST an attached file. this wont have the Gzip parts, but it should have al l the relevant other parts. like Length,  MINE type and others.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but your **web client** should be setting `Accept-Encoding: gzip` in the headers to tell the server that it can accept gzip, should the server wish to (optionally) encode the response.  The **server** on the other hand, adds `Content-Encoding: gzip` to the header of the response to tell the client that the response has actually been encoded (if indeed it was), and using which encoding mechanism.

None of this to my knowledge has anything to do with which HTTP method you are using, it is the same for GET, PUT, POST, the lot.  It is simply used in the headers to communicate metadata about the response.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding) - see *Examples -
Compressing with gzip*

Comment: Your client and server interaction model is backwards for my question.  `Accept-Encoding: gzip` is signified by the client that it is able to accept gzipped responses from the server. It is true that the server communicates to the client `Content-Encoding: gzip` if the response body is gzipped. But the client is the one who sets `Content-Encoding: gzip` on a POST if it wants to indicate to the server that the POST body being delivered is gzipped. Servers don't typically allow you to POST zipped content by default. That is what I am needing to enable.

Comment: Gotcha!  Sorry, I misunderstood the question - yes, even though you said it right there in the bold typeface(!).  I'll leave my answer here in case it helps someone else down the track.

Comment: Does this page help, or the blog post the answer references? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671216/how-do-i-enable-gzip-compression-for-post-upload-requests-to-a-soap-webservice